# Node.js Google Drive api list files in team drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of all files in a google team drive.  The code is as follows:

```
drive.files.list({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    corpora: "teamDrive",
    includeTeamDriveItems: true,
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    teamDriveId: someId
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("The API returned an error: " + err;
        return;
    }

    console.log(response);
});
```

However, this only returns files located in my own drive, and not those located in the shared drive.

I then went to [files.list documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it) and, using the "Try this API" box on the side, entered the exact same information (along with the same scope, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive), and authenticated with the same google account.  This returned the files located in the team drive, as expected.

So, what am I doing wrong in my code that would cause it to not return the files in the team drive, and what changes do I have to make in order to make it work?

Comment: Can you try removing that "corpora":"teamDrive"  or change it to corpora: "domain"?

Comment: @noogui no luck with either.  Still just getting the files in my own drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause and solution thanks to [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/946) on the github page.

Basically, the quickstart guide google provides tells you to use the package google-auth-library@0.*, which is a huge mistake.  It seems as though v0.* of the google-auth-library incorrectly handles parameters that you pass, meaning they don't get included in the request.  Fortunately, the googleapis package includes its own, more recent, version of google-auth-library, so you can just use that for authentication.  Once that's changed, the code in my original question works as expected.